# Data Binding in if statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

In an aspx page i have:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}",Eval("CatalogID"))%>'>
<asp:Label id="lblCustItem" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustItem")%>' width="15%">
</asp:Label>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

And now I am trying to do:

```
<%if (Eval("Integration").ToString() == "Y")
{ %>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/integration/vendorframe.aspx?CatalogID={0}",Eval("CatalogID"))%>'>
<asp:Label id="CustItemlbl" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustItem")%>' width="15%">
</asp:Label>
</asp:HyperLink>
<%} %>

<%else
{ %>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}",Eval("CatalogID"))%>'>
<asp:Label id="lblCustItem" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustItem")%>' width="15%">
</asp:Label>
</asp:HyperLink>
<%} %>
```

the page errors out on the second segment of code. So my question is, am i doing something wrong, and is there a better way to use an if statement, like the conditional if, but i do need to run a new instance of string.format thats why I was thinking that wasn't an option.

Error Message:
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: "the page errors out" - Can you at least provide the error and where the error is thrown?

Comment: How are you binding data from the server side? Is this hyperlink placed in a grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use an Inline If:

```
Text='<%# (Eval("Integration").ToString() == "Y") ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustItem") : "" %>'
```

It's not pretty, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: after seeing this I did try something similar, 

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;" NavigateUrl='<%# (Eval("Integration").ToString() == "Y") ? String.Format("~integration/vendorframe.aspx?CatalogID={0}",Eval("CatalogID")) : String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}",Eval("CatalogID"))%>'>
and i think it would have worked, but it turns out, I was wrong and it is not looking at the right table to get "integration"

Comment: Well, that's a separate issue that you haven't posted details on. If this post solved the initial problem, consider marking it as "Accepted" and creating a separate question if you're having another issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Within the Formview.

```
    <div id="PermDiv" runat="server" visible='<%#(Eval("Permissions").Equals("Edit") ? true : false  ) %>'></div>
```